# Best approach for Oracle Database Tables Auto Purging

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have many tables in my Oracle Databases for which i need to schedule purging on the basis of Date Column.

Current Approach we am using - Scheduled a job which runs query to move data from Transaction table to Backup Table and then delete same from Transaction table.

Please suggest if there is any better/inbuilt approach, like i can define purging logic at the time of Table Creation or any other.

Databse Oracle 12c EE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to use partitioning, and partition the table on Date column. You can then purge (drop partition) or move (partition exchange) depending on your needs.
There is also a full blown ILM (Information Lifecycle Management) capability; take a look at

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/performance/implementingilmdb12c-2543023.pdf

Comment: This is a classic use for Partitioning. However, we always need to mention that Partitioning is **a chargeable extra** to the Enterprise Edition. Otherwise you might lead people into breaching their licenses.